# Unable to get hebrew results using JsonP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, jsonp

I'm doing a JsonP request to a php script hosted on a website i have.
The php script get results from DB and return them as Json.

The problem is that the DB contains Hebrew chars and i get them as '??????' in the response.

Any idea how to solve this?

Here is the js code:

```
$.getJSON("http://flyfish.co.il/appdiet?callback=?",function(data){
$('p').text(data[0].food_name);
});
```

and the php code:

```
 <?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require_once 'config.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

$query = "SELECT * from mytable";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
{
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $data[] = $row;     
}
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($data).')';
}  
else {
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.$mysqli->error.')';
} 
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`? Umm? **text/html**?!

Comment: This isn't JSON. It is JSON-P, so the correct MIME type is `application/javascript`.

Comment: Hi, I changed it but it didn't do the trick :(, also tried application/json with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `set names 'utf8';` before your `select` statement.

Comment: Tried that, now I'm getting : \u05d0\u05e8\u05d8\u05d9\u05e9\u05d5\u05e7

Comment: I read hebrew and that is not hebrew! I don't think there is even a german word that long :)

Comment: When I convert the JSON to text I get `" ארטישוק"` … that doesn't seem long to me.

Comment: what do you mean "when i convert the JSON to text"? how do you convert it?